# Custom entity field is missing in Add content form

Tags: 7, nodes, taxonomy-terms

Created a content type 'News' having fields 'title', 'body' and a custom entity field 'Department'-which will be populated from department vocabulary terms. I can add contents by loging as admin. I can see all the fields for Add 'News' when I login as admin. Now I created a role, 'Content Writer' and given permission to Add 'News' Content and Edit Own Content.

1) From the Navigation menu I can see the add 'News' form also. But the form is missing the custom entity filed 'Department'. What I did wrong/missed?

2) How can I hide the bottom portion(Revision information, publishing options etc.,) of the form for such users

Comment: Can you explain more about you mean by "custom entity field"? Is it a field you added via the content type fields user interface or is it custom code? If custom code can you post the code?

Comment: It would also be better for you to split this into two questions because you 1 & 2 questions are unrelated and it is best to keep one question per stack exchange question.